# Result of call is unused

Tags: swift, function, closures

Right below the second comment, I receive an error of "Result of call to 'taskForDeleteMethod' is unused. Why is this when I use the results and error in the closure following the call?

```
func deleteSession(_ completionHandlerForDeleteSession: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {

    /* 1. Specify parameters, method (if has {key}), and HTTP body (if POST) */
    // There are none...

    /* 2. Make the request */
    taskForDELETEMethod { (results, error) in

        /* 3. Send the desired value(s) to completion handler */
        if let error = error {
            print("Post error: \(error)")
            completionHandlerForDeleteSession(false, error)
        } else {
            guard let session = results![JSONKeys.session] as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                print("No key '\(JSONKeys.session)' in \(results)")
                return
            }

            if let id = session[JSONKeys.id] as? String {
                print("logout id: \(id)")
                completionHandlerForDeleteSession(true, nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the `results` variable, which is, indeed, used inside the closure, and the result of the `taskForDELETEMethod` call itself, which is `NSURLSessionDataTask` object.

From the examples of using `taskForDELETEMethod` that I was able to find online it looks like it is perfectly OK to ignore the return value, so you can avoid this warning by assigning the result to `_` variable, i.e.

```
let _ = taskForDELETEMethod {
    ... // The rest of your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In **earlier swift versions**, you need not bother about the return value of a method. You may store it in any variable snd use it later or you may ignore it completely. Neither it gave any error nor a warning.

But in **swift 3.0** you need to specify whether you want to ignore the returned value or use it.

**1**. If you want to use the returned value, you can create a variable/constant and store the value in it, i.e

```
let value = taskForDELETEMethod {
    // Your code goes here
}
```

**2**. If you want to ignore the returned value, you can use **_** ,i.e

```
let _ = taskForDELETEMethod {
    // Your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Even better, you can just do '_ = method()'. When you don't need the return value you don't have to specify let.