# Result of call to finalizeStatusForAccount is Unused in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

[image: I'm getting these two warnings can anyone please suggest how to remove these warnings]

```
self.coreDataStack.finalizeStatusForAccount(currentAccount, fromStatus: ObjectStatus.tempClear, toStatus: ObjectStatus.clear)
self.coreDataStack.finalizeStatusForAccount(currentAccount, fromStatus: ObjectStatus.tempGreen, toStatus: ObjectStatus.green)
```

I'm getting these two warnings can anyone please suggest how to remove these warnings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Result of call is unused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692602/result-of-call-is-unused)

Answer (score 0):

The warning says that the function `finalizeStatusForAccount` returns a value yet you don’t use it. You might want to assign the return value to a variable, like this:

```
let returnValue = self.coreDataStack.finalizeStatusForAccount...
```

Or if you know you don’t need to check the return value you would write this:

```
let _ = self.coreDataStack.finalizeStatusForAccount...
```

The latter is a standard pattern in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your function `finalizeStatusForAccount` you can add `@discardableResult` this way:

```
@discardableResult
func finalizeStatusForAccount() -> Any {
    return 100500
}
```